# What does the proxy_pass option in the NGINX config do?

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

What does the NGINX proxy_pass config do? Let's say for example I have a Django app that is hosted up on Amazon's EC2 services.

On EC2, let's say I have 1 load balancer in front of 2 nginx servers. The nginx servers point to the 4 django app servers that use Gunicorn as there WSGI server:

```
upstream my-upstream {
 server 12.34.45.65:8000;
 server 13.43.54.56:8000;
 server 13.46.56.52:8000;
 server 14.46.58.51:8000;
}

location / {
proxy_pass http://my-upstream;
}
```

What is the proxy_pass? would it be the URL of the load balancer in this case?

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [nginx's HttpProxyModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule), which is where proxy_pass comes from. The [proxy_pass docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass) say:

> This directive sets the address of the proxied server and the URI to
>   which location will be mapped.

So when you tell Nginx to `proxy_pass`, you're saying "Pass this request on to this proxy URL".

There's also documentation on [upstream](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule#upstream) available:

> This directive describes a set of servers, which can be used in
>   directives proxy_pass and fastcgi_pass as a single entity.

So the reason that you use upstream for proxy_pass is because proxy_pass is expecting one URL, but you want to pass it more than one (so you use an upstream).

If your load balancer is in front of your nginx, your load balancer URL won't be in this config.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:
proxy_pass http://my-upstream;

nginx will load-balance all requests over your 4 djano+gunicorn instances (your my-upstream). The load-balancers will point to the nginx servers.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for, I will give it a try and let you know

Comment: This is wrong. Unless you add the scheme http/https, it'll give the error - nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /.../conf/nginx.conf:xx